# Server Controller - access specific record

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am new to writing components.  I have some experience with VF pages.  Based on an example I found on the internet, I have code that displays a list of campaign members & allows me to select certain ones & update their statuses.  Right now this does it for all campaign members on all campaigns.

I want to have my component reside on a Campaign page & relate to that specific page.  In VF I would accomplish this type of task with code that looks something like:

```
ApexPages.StandardController con;
contact ee;
List<campaignMember>lstcampaigns = new List<campaignMember>();
public DisplayContactCampaigns2(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    con=controller;
}
public List<campaignMember>getconts()
{
    ee=(contact)con.getRecord();

    lstcampaigns=[select id,name,campaign_Name__c, Display_Campaign_Start_Date__c, status 
                  from campaignMember 
                  where contactid=:ee.id and (status='Attended')
                  order by campaign_Name__c];
    return lstcampaigns;
```

When I try to do a similar thing in my Apex associated with a component, I am getting errors that my `ee` variable is not accessible.

I think the problem has to do with the fact that my VF code works with the constructor & methods in the component apex need to be static.

Comment: For visualforce to know about any controller property, they should be declared as [getter/setter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm).

Comment: Rahul,

I am trying to do this one as a component.   I can get this kind of thing to work in VF.   Do you have an example of doing this as a component?  Thank you.  Michele

Comment: No need to be so formal with your comment structure. Does your code work as expected when you change `contact ee;` to provide a getter & setter, ie, `public contact ee { get; set }`?

Comment: It does not.  I am really shaky on what I am doing.  Below is my code:

Comment: public with sharing class DeleteWithCheckboxController {    
 ApexPages.StandardController con;
    public DeleteWithCheckboxController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){        con=controller;}
    @AuraEnabled
       public campaign ee { get; set; }
    public static list < campaignMember > fetchContact() {
           ee=(campaign)con.getRecord();
        list < campaignMember > returnConList = new List < campaignMember > ();
        List < campaignMember > lstCon = [SELECT FirstName, LastName, CompanyOrAccount, Status   From campaignMember WHERE campaignid=:ee.id

Comment: How can I post my code in a comment to look better?

Comment: Are you talking about Lightning components or Visualforce components?  BTW you cannot format code in a comment, so it's best to edit your original post and include all relevant code.

Comment: I have moved my first Lightning component into production.  I haven't found how to reference the record that I am currently on when the Lightning component is called.  The way I was doing it on my VF page doesn't seem to work.  In summary, I think I am missing a few lines of code that need to go into my server controller code for my Lightning component.